# Soketi & Echo doesn't work with SSL and doesn't authorize Private channels

Tags: laravel, nginx, websocket, pusher

Setup:

- Forge
- Nginx
- Soketi
- Echo
- Laravel
- Sanctum

Issues:

- SSL doesn't work. Error: `WebSocket connection to 'wss://IP:6002/app/payload' failed:`
- When using WS instead of WSS -> Error: `Connection is not authorized`.

Idea for first issue:

- Force WSS
- Request to port 6002
- Nginx "proxies" it to 6001

Suggestions:

- My Nginx' config is incorrect
- I should be connecting to another port

Info:

- ports 6001 & 6002 => open

.env

```
PUSHER_HOST=IP
PUSHER_APP_ID=APPID
PUSHER_APP_KEY=KEY
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=SECRET
PUSHER_APP_PORT=6002

PUSHER_APP_ENCRYPTED=true
PUSHER_APP_SCHEMA=https
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="eu-central-1"

MIX_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_PORT="${PUSHER_APP_PORT}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_ENCRYPTED="${PUSHER_APP_ENCRYPTED}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
MIX_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_APP_PORT}"
```

auth.php

```
'defaults' => array(
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ),

'guards' => array(
        'web' => array(
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ),

        'api' => array(
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ),
    ),
```

BroadcastServiceProvider

```
public function boot() {
        Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => ['auth:api']]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');
    }
```

Echo

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    host: `${process.env.MIX_APP_HOST}:${process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_PORT}`,
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_HOST,
    wsPort: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_PORT,
    wssPort: "6002",
    forceTLS: true,
    enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
    encrypted: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_ENCRYPTED,
    reconnection: true,
    enableLogging: true,
    disableStats: true,
    authorizer: (channel, options) => {
        return {
            authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
                console.log("Requested something")
                axios.post('/api/broadcasting/auth', {
                    socket_id: socketId,
                    channel_name: channel.name
                })
                    .then(response => {
                        console.log(response)
                        callback(false, response);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        callback(true, error);
                    });
            }
        };
    },
});
```

api.php

```
Route::prefix('broadcasting')->controller(BroadcastingController::class)->group(function () {
    Route::post('/auth', 'validateWebsocket');
});
```

BroadcastingController

```
public function validateWebsocket(Request $request) {
        Log::debug("socket_id: " . $request->get("socket_id") . ", channel_name: " . $request->get("channel_name"));
        return response()->json([], 200);
    }
```

Channels

```
Broadcast::channel('users.{userId}', function ($user, $userId) {
    Log::debug("Requesting");
    return empty($user) === false && $user->id == $userId;
});
```

Nginx

server {
listen 6002 ssl http2;
listen [::]:6002 ssl http2;
server_name WEBSITE;
server_tokens off;

```
  # FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/WEBSITE/PATH/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/WEBSITE/PATH/server.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers CIPHER;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers off;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

location / {
    proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:6001;
    proxy_read_timeout     60;
    proxy_connect_timeout  60;
    proxy_redirect         off;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}

access_log /home/forge/WEBSITE/so_ac.log;
error_log  /home/forge/WEBSITE/so_er.log error;
```

}

config.json

```
{
  "debug": true,
  "port": 6002,
  "appManager.array.apps": [
    {
      "id": "ID",
      "key": "KEY",
      "secret": "SECRET"
    }
  ],
  "ssl": {
        "certPath": "PATH",
        "keyPath": "PATH"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `validateWebsocket`, it should be

```
$pusher = new Pusher(env("PUSHER_APP_KEY"), env("PUSHER_APP_SECRET"), env("PUSHER_APP_ID"));
return $pusher->socket_auth($channel_name, $socket_id);
```

Update #1:

In case you're blocking all of your routes and you would like to use `channels.php` then you should redirect the request. The issue was that the route was not found due to custom routing that I've implemented that blocked the access.

Place this in your `api.php` for example, and set the `authEndpoint` in your Echo configuration to `authEndpoint: "/api/broadcasting/auth",`

```
Route::prefix('broadcasting')->group(function () {
    // broadcasting/auth
    Route::post('/auth', [BroadcastController::class, 'authenticate']);
});
```

For WSS, the only workaround was to connect to WS and then upgrade it to WSS. Any better suggestion is welcome!